# Pusher auth endpoint gives me a 404 error

Tags: javascript, pusher, pusher-js

I am using `pusher-js` in react. My frontend is served at app.xxx.com and my backend is served at api.xxx.com. We have a private notification websocket channel to push notiifcations through app.xxx.com. What i'm trying to achieve is using the auth endpoint on backend. But no matter what i do, pusher will always request to the base URL of frontend plus auth endpoint. In my case it will be `https://app.xxx.com/broadcasting/auth` but i want it to be `https://api.xxx.com/broadcasting/auth`. What should i do? Here's my pusher config:

```
pusher = new Pusher(APP_ID, {
                httpHost: process.env.REACT_APP_WS_HOST,
                authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
                auth: {
                    params: {
                        id: userData.id,
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    }
                },
                cluster: 'ap2',
                wsHost: process.env.REACT_APP_WS_HOST,
                wsPort: 6001,
                wssPort: 6001,
                forceTLS: true,
            })
```

The value of `process.env.REACT_APP_WS_HOST` is `api.xxx.com`

**UPDATE**:
I even tried adding an `authHost` key but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the full URL to the endpoint:

```
authEndpoint: 'https://api.xxx.com/broadcasting/auth'
```

Comment: But how do you know the exact endpoint url? As I first set up pusher everything worked fine without even defining an `authEndpoint`, but the next day I got the same error message.